# Is this C code acceptable for finding the no.of occurences for each integer in an array? Which I tried for short code aim

Tags: arrays, c, indexing, shortcut

If this has any error, kindly mention it. Because I may figure out some future consequences

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,4,5},count[10]={0},i;
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);i++)
    {
        int x;
        x=a[i];
        count[x]=count[x]+1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(count)/sizeof(count[0]);i++)
    {
        if(count[i]!=0)
        {
            printf("\n %d:%d",i,count[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which language? Please add an appropriate tag. It looks like C but lots of other languages look like C too, in particular C++.

Comment: The main issues I have with your code are style ones. The `int a[]=...` line is messy, with two arrays being both defined and initialized, plus a loop counter. These should be 3 separate lines, for cleanliness. Another note is that it's relatively fragile. If you supply an `a` array with any number greater than 9, you'll be modifying data out of bounds of the `count` array.

Comment: This piece of code takes much more reading effort than it should.

Comment: `count[x]=count[x]+1`  is simpler and clearer as `count[x]++`

Comment: "Does my code work?" is not really an appropriate question on SO. You need to try it out yourself with various test cases; this is not something that other users will generally do for you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally? No. In this specific case? Maybe.

- Instead of `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`, use a macro to get the array size.
- Dont declare/initialize a loop variable and two arrays in one line.
- You will get out of bounds issues as soon as a contains `a` number that is bigger than the length of `count` - 1 or smaller than 0.

I would do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAY_COUNT(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))

void GetCountOfNumberInArray(int intArray[],
                             unsigned int intArraySize,
                             int numbersToCount[],
                             unsigned int numberCount[],
                             unsigned int numbersToCountSize){
    memset(numberCount, 0, numbersToCountSize * sizeof(numbersToCountSize));
    unsigned int count = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < intArraySize; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < numbersToCountSize; j++){
            if(numbersToCount[j] == intArray[i]){
                numberCount[j]++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int intArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1};
    int numbersToCount[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    unsigned int numberCount[ARRAY_COUNT(numbersToCount)];
    GetCountOfNumberInArray(intArray,
                            ARRAY_COUNT(intArray),
                            numbersToCount,
                            numberCount,
                            ARRAY_COUNT(numbersToCount));
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < ARRAY_COUNT(numbersToCount); i++){
        printf("number %i appears %u times in the array\n", numbersToCount[i], numberCount[i]);
    }
}
```

That way you get a universal function to count a set of numbers in an array that still works similar to your original solution.